# I want to check the different attributes if .tiff image files like Clipping path availability ,alpha channel ,pixel size etc , using Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, tiff

I am calling  the images with pillow library , then I want to know how to collect the information about these attributes about all these images in a tabular form and then would like to export as excel .

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open(r"C:\\Users\\inpunindg\\Downloads\\Images\\test_image.tif")

img1=Image.open(r"C:\\Users\\inpunindg\\Downloads\\Images\\02444349.tif")

img2=Image.open(r"C:\\Users\\inpunindg\\Downloads\\Images\\02445323.tif")

print(type(img))

print(type(img1))

print(type(img2))
```

I am very new in this field , any help is appreciated ..thankyou in advance.

Comment: You would probably be better off with a one-liner using `exiftool` which can produce CSV output for import into Excel.

Comment: It would be easier to assist you better if you provided a link to an image that has all the things you are looking for. You can use Dropbox or Google Drive to share.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZRHSXBDMEbRiMYjFsrK9AIuXWTNaZQf/view?usp=sharing  hello @Mark Setchell -here is the link containing one image with all the requisites.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can get quite a lot of the information you require most simply with `exiftool`. So, for example, here are the image name, height and width and clipping channel name as a CSV - I am just using one image but you can replace the image name in the following command with `*.tif` for example:

```
exiftool -p '$fileName,$ImageHeight,$ImageWidth,$AlphaChannelsNames'  20235976.tif 
20235976.tif,2411,3400,Alpha 1
```

---

You can get a lot more verbose output to identify other parameters you might want to extract using:

```
exiftool -v -v -v IMAGE.TIF

  ExifToolVersion = 12.60
  FileName = 20235976.tif
  Directory = .
  FileSize = 2102488
  FileModifyDate = 1690923306
  FileAccessDate = 1690995420
  FileInodeChangeDate = 1690923306
  FilePermissions = 33188
  FileType = TIFF
  FileTypeExtension = TIF
  MIMEType = image/tiff
  ExifByteOrder = II
  + [IFD0 directory with 22 entries]
  | 0)  SubfileType = 0
  |     - Tag 0x00fe (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         0012: 00 00 00 00                                     [....]
  | 1)  ImageWidth = 3400
  |     - Tag 0x0100 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         001e: 48 0d                                           [H.]
  | 2)  ImageHeight = 2411
  |     - Tag 0x0101 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         002a: 6b 09                                           [k.]
  | 3)  BitsPerSample = 8 8 8 8
  |     - Tag 0x0102 (8 bytes, int16u[4]):
  |         0116: 08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00                         [........]
  | 4)  Compression = 5
  |     - Tag 0x0103 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0042: 05 00                                           [..]
  | 5)  PhotometricInterpretation = 2
  |     - Tag 0x0106 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         004e: 02 00                                           [..]
  | 6)  StripOffsets = 25514 26426 27338 28250 29162 30074 30986 31898 32810 33722 3463[snip]
  |     - Tag 0x0111 (508 bytes, int32u[127]):
  |         011e: aa 63 00 00 3a 67 00 00 ca 6a 00 00 5a 6e 00 00 [.c..:g...j..Zn..]
  |         012e: ea 71 00 00 7a 75 00 00 0a 79 00 00 9a 7c 00 00 [.q..zu...y...|..]
  |         013e: 2a 80 00 00 ba 83 00 00 4a 87 00 00 da 8a 00 00 [*.......J.......]
  |         014e: 6a 8e 00 00 fa 91 00 00 8a 95 00 00 1a 99 00 00 [j...............]
  |         015e: aa 9c 00 00 3a a0 00 00 ca a3 00 00 58 af 00 00 [....:.......X...]
  |         [snip 428 bytes]
  | 7)  Orientation = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0112 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0066: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 8)  SamplesPerPixel = 4
  |     - Tag 0x0115 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0072: 04 00                                           [..]
  | 9)  RowsPerStrip = 19
  |     - Tag 0x0116 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         007e: 13 00                                           [..]
  | 10) StripByteCounts = 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 911 9[snip]
  |     - Tag 0x0117 (508 bytes, int32u[127]):
  |         031a: 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 [................]
  |         032a: 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 [................]
  |         033a: 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 [................]
  |         034a: 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 [................]
  |         035a: 8f 03 00 00 8f 03 00 00 8e 0b 00 00 f9 10 00 00 [................]
  |         [snip 428 bytes]
  | 11) XResolution = 300 (3000000/10000)
  |     - Tag 0x011a (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         0516: c0 c6 2d 00 10 27 00 00                         [..-..'..]
  | 12) YResolution = 300 (3000000/10000)
  |     - Tag 0x011b (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         051e: c0 c6 2d 00 10 27 00 00                         [..-..'..]
  | 13) PlanarConfiguration = 1
  |     - Tag 0x011c (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00ae: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 14) ResolutionUnit = 2
  |     - Tag 0x0128 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00ba: 02 00                                           [..]
  | 15) Software = Adobe Photoshop 24.5 (Windows)
  |     - Tag 0x0131 (31 bytes, string[31]):
  |         0526: 41 64 6f 62 65 20 50 68 6f 74 6f 73 68 6f 70 20 [Adobe Photoshop ]
  |         0536: 32 34 2e 35 20 28 57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 29 00    [24.5 (Windows).]
  | 16) ModifyDate = 2023:06:20 09:32:46
  |     - Tag 0x0132 (20 bytes, string[20]):
  |         0546: 32 30 32 33 3a 30 36 3a 32 30 20 30 39 3a 33 32 [2023:06:20 09:32]
  |         0556: 3a 34 36 00                                     [:46.]
  | 17) Predictor = 2
  |     - Tag 0x013d (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00de: 02 00                                           [..]
  | 18) ExtraSamples = 0
  |     - Tag 0x0152 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00ea: 00 00                                           [..]
  | 19) ApplicationNotes (SubDirectory) -->
  |     - Tag 0x02bc (15225 bytes, int8u[15225] read as undef[15225]):
  |         055a: 3c 3f 78 70 61 63 6b 65 74 20 62 65 67 69 6e 3d [<?xpacket begin=]
  |         056a: 22 ef bb bf 22 20 69 64 3d 22 57 35 4d 30 4d 70 ["..." id="W5M0Mp]
  |         057a: 43 65 68 69 48 7a 72 65 53 7a 4e 54 63 7a 6b 63 [CehiHzreSzNTczkc]
  |         058a: 39 64 22 3f 3e 0a 3c 78 3a 78 6d 70 6d 65 74 61 [9d"?>.<x:xmpmeta]
  |         059a: 20 78 6d 6c 6e 73 3a 78 3d 22 61 64 6f 62 65 3a [ xmlns:x="adobe:]
  |         [snip 15145 bytes]
  | + [XMP directory, 15225 bytes]
  | | XMPToolkit = Adobe XMP Core 9.0-c001 79.c0204b2, 2023/02/09-06:26:14        
  | | CreatorTool = Adobe Photoshop 24.5 (Windows)
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmp:CreatorTool'
  | | CreateDate = 2023-06-20T09:18:29+05:30
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmp:CreateDate'
  | | ModifyDate = 2023-06-20T09:32:46+05:30
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmp:ModifyDate'
  | | MetadataDate = 2023-06-20T09:32:46+05:30
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmp:MetadataDate'
  | | Format = image/tiff
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/dc:format'
  | | ColorMode = 3
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/photoshop:ColorMode'
  | | InstanceID = xmp.iid:92ac0d0e-d3f1-b74e-abd9-35326db1ffff
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:InstanceID'
  | | DocumentID = adobe:docid:photoshop:960a4e52-2d04-8143-b9e9-3b3bc51387de
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:DocumentID'
  | | OriginalDocumentID = xmp.did:91abf09a-bf34-4147-894d-25d4fddb001a
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID'
  | | HistoryAction = created
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 10/stEvt:action'
  | | HistoryInstanceID = xmp.iid:91abf09a-bf34-4147-894d-25d4fddb001a
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 10/stEvt:instanceID'
  | | HistoryWhen = 2023-06-20T09:18:29+05:30
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 10/stEvt:when'
  | | HistorySoftwareAgent = Adobe Photoshop 24.5 (Windows)
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 10/stEvt:softwareAgent'
  | | HistoryAction = saved
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 11/stEvt:action'
  | | HistoryInstanceID = xmp.iid:92ac0d0e-d3f1-b74e-abd9-35326db1ffff
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 11/stEvt:instanceID'
  | | HistoryWhen = 2023-06-20T09:32:46+05:30
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 11/stEvt:when'
  | | HistorySoftwareAgent = Adobe Photoshop 24.5 (Windows)
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 11/stEvt:softwareAgent'
  | | HistoryChanged = /
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/xmpMM:History/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 11/stEvt:changed'
  | | ImageWidth = 3400
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:ImageWidth'
  | | ImageHeight = 2411
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:ImageLength'
  | | BitsPerSample = 8
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:BitsPerSample/rdf:Seq/rdf:li 10'
  | | Compression = 1
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:Compression'
  | | PhotometricInterpretation = 2
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:PhotometricInterpretation'
  | | Orientation = 1
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:Orientation'
  | | SamplesPerPixel = 4
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:SamplesPerPixel'
  | | XResolution = 3000000/10000
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:XResolution'
  | | YResolution = 3000000/10000
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:YResolution'
  | | ResolutionUnit = 2
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/tiff:ResolutionUnit'
  | | ColorSpace = 65535
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/exif:ColorSpace'
  | | ExifImageWidth = 3400
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/exif:PixelXDimension'
  | | ExifImageHeight = 2411
  | | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/exif:PixelYDimension'
  | 20) PhotoshopSettings (SubDirectory) -->
  |     - Tag 0x8649 (8918 bytes, int8u[8918] read as undef[8918]):
  |         40d4: 38 42 49 4d 04 25 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 [8BIM.%..........]
  |         40e4: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 42 49 4d [............8BIM]
  |         40f4: 04 3a 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 [.:..............]
  |         4104: 00 00 00 00 00 0b 70 72 69 6e 74 4f 75 74 70 75 [......printOutpu]
  |         4114: 74 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 50 73 74 53 62 6f 6f [t........PstSboo]
  |         [snip 8838 bytes]
  | + [Photoshop directory, 8918 bytes]
  | | IPTCDigest = 
  | | - Tag 0x0425 (16 bytes):
  | |     40e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | | PrintInfo2 = ...printOutput.PstSbool.InteenumInteClrm.printSixteenBitbool.printer[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x043a (229 bytes):
  | |     40fc: 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 0b 70 72 [..............pr]
  | |     410c: 69 6e 74 4f 75 74 70 75 74 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 [intOutput.......]
  | |     411c: 00 50 73 74 53 62 6f 6f 6c 01 00 00 00 00 49 6e [.PstSbool.....In]
  | |     412c: 74 65 65 6e 75 6d 00 00 00 00 49 6e 74 65 00 00 [teenum....Inte..]
  | |     413c: 00 00 43 6c 72 6d 00 00 00 0f 70 72 69 6e 74 53 [..Clrm....printS]
  | |     [snip 149 bytes]
  | | PrintStyle = ...printOutputOptions.CptnboolClbrboolRgsMboolCrnCboolCntCboolLblsbo[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x043b (557 bytes):
  | |     41ee: 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 12 70 72 [..............pr]
  | |     41fe: 69 6e 74 4f 75 74 70 75 74 4f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 [intOutputOptions]
  | |     420e: 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 43 70 74 6e 62 6f 6f 6c [........Cptnbool]
  | |     421e: 00 00 00 00 00 43 6c 62 72 62 6f 6f 6c 00 00 00 [.....Clbrbool...]
  | |     422e: 00 00 52 67 73 4d 62 6f 6f 6c 00 00 00 00 00 43 [..RgsMbool.....C]
  | |     [snip 477 bytes]
  | | ResolutionInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  | | - Tag 0x03ed (16 bytes):
  | |     4428: 01 2c 00 00 00 01 00 01 01 2c 00 00 00 01 00 01 [.,.......,......]
  | | + [BinaryData directory, 16 bytes]
  | | | XResolution = 19660800
  | | | - Tag 0x0000 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | | |     4428: 01 2c 00 00                                     [.,..]
  | | | DisplayedUnitsX = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x0002 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  | | |     442c: 00 01                                           [..]
  | | | YResolution = 19660800
  | | | - Tag 0x0004 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | | |     4430: 01 2c 00 00                                     [.,..]
  | | | DisplayedUnitsY = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x0006 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  | | |     4434: 00 01                                           [..]
  | | PrintScaleInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  | | - Tag 0x0426 (14 bytes):
  | |     4444: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 80 00 00       [..........?...]
  | | + [BinaryData directory, 14 bytes]
  | | | PrintStyle = 0
  | | | - Tag 0x0000 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  | | |     4444: 00 00                                           [..]
  | | | PrintPosition = 0 0
  | | | - Tag 0x0002 (8 bytes, float[2]):
  | | |     4446: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [........]
  | | | PrintScale = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x000a (4 bytes, float[1]):
  | | |     444e: 3f 80 00 00                                     [?...]
  | | AlphaChannelsNames = .Alpha 1
  | | - Tag 0x03ee (8 bytes):
  | |     445e: 07 41 6c 70 68 61 20 31                         [.Alpha 1]
  | | UnicodeAlphaNames = .Alpha 1
  | | - Tag 0x0415 (20 bytes):
  | |     4472: 00 00 00 08 00 41 00 6c 00 70 00 68 00 61 00 20 [.....A.l.p.h.a. ]
  | |     4482: 00 31 00 00                                     [.1..]
  | | DisplayInfo = ...2.
  | | - Tag 0x0435 (17 bytes):
  | |     4492: 00 00 00 01 00 00 ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 [...............2]
  | |     44a2: 01                                              [.]
  | | AlphaIdentifiers = .
  | | - Tag 0x041d (4 bytes):
  | |     44b0: 00 00 00 04                                     [....]
  | | GlobalAngle = .
  | | - Tag 0x040d (4 bytes):
  | |     44c0: 00 00 00 1e                                     [....]
  | | GlobalAltitude = .
  | | - Tag 0x0419 (4 bytes):
  | |     44d0: 00 00 00 1e                                     [....]
  | | PrintFlags = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  | | - Tag 0x03f3 (9 bytes, int8u[9]):
  | |     44e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01                      [.........]
  | | PrintFlagsInfo = ..
  | | - Tag 0x2710 (10 bytes):
  | |     44f6: 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01                   [..........]
  | | ColorHalftoningInfo = /ff.lff../ff......2.Z..5.-..
  | | - Tag 0x03f5 (72 bytes):
  | |     450c: 00 2f 66 66 00 01 00 6c 66 66 00 06 00 00 00 00 [./ff...lff......]
  | |     451c: 00 01 00 2f 66 66 00 01 00 a1 99 9a 00 06 00 00 [.../ff..........]
  | |     452c: 00 00 00 01 00 32 00 00 00 01 00 5a 00 00 00 06 [.....2.....Z....]
  | |     453c: 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 35 00 00 00 01 00 2d 00 00 [.......5.....-..]
  | |     454c: 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 01                         [........]
  | | ColorTransferFuncs = ............................................................[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x03f8 (112 bytes):
  | |     4560: 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff [................]
  | |     4570: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 03 e8 00 00 00 00 ff ff [................]
  | |     4580: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff [................]
  | |     4590: ff ff ff ff 03 e8 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff [................]
  | |     45a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff [................]
  | |     [snip 32 bytes]
  | | GridGuidesInfo = ..@.@
  | | - Tag 0x0408 (16 bytes):
  | |     45dc: 00 00 00 01 00 00 02 40 00 00 02 40 00 00 00 00 [.......@...@....]
  | | Photoshop_0x0444 = ..@.@
  | | - Tag 0x0444 (16 bytes):
  | |     45f8: 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 40 00 00 02 40 00 00 00 00 [.......@...@....]
  | | URL_List = 
  | | - Tag 0x041e (4 bytes):
  | |     4614: 00 00 00 00                                     [....]
  | | SliceInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  | | - Tag 0x041a (837 bytes):
  | |     4624: 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 6b [...............k]
  | |     4634: 00 00 0d 48 00 00 00 08 00 30 00 32 00 34 00 34 [...H.....0.2.4.4]
  | |     4644: 00 34 00 33 00 34 00 39 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 [.4.3.4.9........]
  | |     4654: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 [................]
  | |     4664: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 48 00 00 09 6b [...........H...k]
  | |     [snip 757 bytes]
  | | + [BinaryData directory, 837 bytes]
  | | | SlicesGroupName = 02444349
  | | | - Tag 0x0014 (16 bytes, ustr32[16]):
  | | |     463c: 00 30 00 32 00 34 00 34 00 34 00 33 00 34 00 39 [.0.2.4.4.4.3.4.9]
  | | | NumSlices = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x0018 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | | |     464c: 00 00 00 01                                     [....]
  | | PixelInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  | | - Tag 0x0428 (12 bytes):
  | |     4976: 00 00 00 02 3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00             [....?.......]
  | | + [BinaryData directory, 12 bytes]
  | | | PixelAspectRatio = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x0004 (8 bytes, double[1]):
  | | |     497a: 3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [?.......]
  | | ICC_Untagged = 1
  | | - Tag 0x0411 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  | |     498e: 01                                              [.]
  | | IDsBaseValue = 4
  | | - Tag 0x0414 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | |     499c: 00 00 00 04                                     [....]
  | | PhotoshopThumbnail = ..q.............Adobe_CM....Adobed..........................[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x040c (2081 bytes):
  | |     49ac: 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 9f 00 00 00 71 00 00 01 e0 [...........q....]
  | |     49bc: 00 00 d3 e0 00 00 08 05 00 18 00 01 ff d8 ff ed [................]
  | |     49cc: 00 0c 41 64 6f 62 65 5f 43 4d 00 02 ff ee 00 0e [..Adobe_CM......]
  | |     49dc: 41 64 6f 62 65 00 64 80 00 00 00 01 ff db 00 84 [Adobe.d.........]
  | |     49ec: 00 0c 08 08 08 09 08 0c 09 09 0c 11 0b 0a 0b 11 [................]
  | |     [snip 2001 bytes]
  | | VersionInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  | | - Tag 0x0421 (87 bytes):
  | |     51da: 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 0f 00 41 00 64 00 6f 00 [..........A.d.o.]
  | |     51ea: 62 00 65 00 20 00 50 00 68 00 6f 00 74 00 6f 00 [b.e. .P.h.o.t.o.]
  | |     51fa: 73 00 68 00 6f 00 70 00 00 00 14 00 41 00 64 00 [s.h.o.p.....A.d.]
  | |     520a: 6f 00 62 00 65 00 20 00 50 00 68 00 6f 00 74 00 [o.b.e. .P.h.o.t.]
  | |     521a: 6f 00 73 00 68 00 6f 00 70 00 20 00 32 00 30 00 [o.s.h.o.p. .2.0.]
  | |     522a: 32 00 33 00 00 00 01                            [2.3....]
  | | + [BinaryData directory, 87 bytes]
  | | | HasRealMergedData = 1
  | | | - Tag 0x0004 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  | | |     51de: 01                                              [.]
  | | | WriterName = Adobe Photoshop
  | | | - Tag 0x0005 (30 bytes, ustr32[30]):
  | | |     51e3: 00 41 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 65 00 20 00 50 00 68 [.A.d.o.b.e. .P.h]
  | | |     51f3: 00 6f 00 74 00 6f 00 73 00 68 00 6f 00 70       [.o.t.o.s.h.o.p]
  | | | ReaderName = Adobe Photoshop 2023
  | | | - Tag 0x0009 (40 bytes, ustr32[40]):
  | | |     5205: 00 41 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 65 00 20 00 50 00 68 [.A.d.o.b.e. .P.h]
  | | |     5215: 00 6f 00 74 00 6f 00 73 00 68 00 6f 00 70 00 20 [.o.t.o.s.h.o.p. ]
  | | |     5225: 00 32 00 30 00 32 00 33                         [.2.0.2.3]
  | | PathSelectionState = ..null.nullobj .prop.PathWrPt
  | | - Tag 0x0440 (64 bytes):
  | |     523e: 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 75 [..............nu]
  | |     524e: 6c 6c 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 6e 75 6c 6c 6f 62 [ll........nullob]
  | |     525e: 6a 20 00 00 00 01 70 72 6f 70 00 00 00 01 00 00 [j ....prop......]
  | |     526e: 00 00 00 00 50 61 74 68 00 00 00 00 57 72 50 74 [....Path....WrPt]
  | | WorkingPath = ..J..$....K$...b.$...]..'1...).1.X...... .6.....?...d.D]...k.K.....[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x0401 (2002 bytes):
  | |     528a: 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     529a: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     52aa: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     52ba: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4a 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 [.......J........]
  | |     52ca: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 [................]
  | |     [snip 1922 bytes]
  | | Photoshop_0x07d0 = ..P...%D..G.%D..G.%D..G..<.....<.....<......Vn7q..Vn7q..Vn7q..[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x07d0, Name="Path 1" (2158 bytes):
  | |     5a6e: 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     5a7e: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     5a8e: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |     5a9e: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 [.......P........]
  | |     5aae: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 [................]
  | |     [snip 2078 bytes]
  | | OriginPathInfo = ..null..keyRootDescriptorListVlLs.Objc.null..keyDescriptorListVl[snip]
  | | - Tag 0x0bb8, Name="OriginDataIRB" (182 bytes):
  | |     62f4: 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 75 [..............nu]
  | |     6304: 6c 6c 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 15 6b 65 79 52 6f 6f [ll........keyRoo]
  | |     6314: 74 44 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 6f 72 4c 69 73 74 56 [tDescriptorListV]
  | |     6324: 6c 4c 73 00 00 00 01 4f 62 6a 63 00 00 00 01 00 [lLs....Objc.....]
  | |     6334: 00 00 00 00 00 6e 75 6c 6c 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 [.....null.......]
  | |     [snip 102 bytes]
  | 21) ExifOffset (SubDirectory) -->
  |     - Tag 0x8769 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         010e: ac 14 20 00                                     [.. .]
  | + [ExifIFD directory with 3 entries]
  | | 0)  ColorSpace = 65535
  | |     - Tag 0xa001 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  | |       2014b6: ff ff                                           [..]
  | | 1)  ExifImageWidth = 3400
  | |     - Tag 0xa002 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | |       2014c2: 48 0d 00 00                                     [H...]
  | | 2)  ExifImageHeight = 2411
  | |     - Tag 0xa003 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  | |       2014ce: 6b 09 00 00                                     [k...]
```

---

You can also detect the presence of the clipping path with **ImageMagick** using:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE.TIF
```

And you can extract the clipping path to an SVG with:

```
magick identify -format '%[8BIM:1999,2998:#1]' 20235976.tif > clip.svg
```